# Online free no-registration app that monitors websites?

Tags: webapp-rec

A website I need to access is currently down (port 80 connection hangs).

Is there a free online no-registration-required service that monitors 
websites that are down and then emails me when the site's back up?

I realize I could write this myself or use Nagios/etc, but it'd be
nice to have a quick-and-dirty website for this.

I also don't want to set up constant or repeating monitoring. I just
want to know when the site is up, and never hear from the app again
(unless I revisit it and ask it to monitor another site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of [uptime checkers](http://www.google.com/search?num=50&q=uptime+service). I use [uptime.openacs.org](http://uptime.openacs.org/uptime/about.adp) because I like the clean interface. :)

It sends a request every 15 minutes. You get an email when your site is down and another one when the site is back again. On some sites I use the service as a poor man’s cron job.